# css class only gets applied every other row

Tags: css, font-awesome

Junior dev question here, a bit complicated. I'm working on a task management piece of a system that gets all the tasks from the db and displays them in rows. There's a show/hide toggle js function i'm using :

```
function NewShowHideDiv(id, disabled) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    $(eval(x)).slideToggle("slow", function() {
});
    return null;
}
```

which handles the toggling of the div. there is a separate function that  function that  handles the icon that you click to expand the div

```
Function ShowHideIcon(divID, Disabled, iconID, icon, iconClass)
    ShowHideIcon = "<i class=""" & iconClass & """ id=""" & iconID & """ onClick=""NewShowHideDiv('" & divID & "', '" & Disabled & "');return false;"">" & icon & "</i>"
End Function
```

the class being applied on click should be

```
i.btnRotate.clicked {
   color:  #009FFF;
   font-family: FontAwesome;
    transform: rotate(540deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

but it's not applying the .clicked class correctly. it skips it on every other row. so if there are 3 rows, only the first and third rows will transform properly, for example.  hope that makes sense. i'm stumped. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [debugger;] like this (below) then make sure iconClass variable = "btnRotate.clicked" in the browser console

```
    Function ShowHideIcon(divID, Disabled, iconID, icon, iconClass)
        debugger;
        ShowHideIcon = "<i class=""" & iconClass & """ id=""" & iconID & """ onClick=""NewShowHideDiv('" & divID & "', '" & Disabled & "');return false;"">" & icon & "</i>"
    End Function
```

Also maybe I'm thinkin its a javascript / ID problem.  Javascript expects only 1 id per page.  If your html has the same id in every other row, its not allowed and javascript will skip it.  A solution would be maybe using a foreach, or just classes but i'd have to see some html to know for sure.

Comment: I think you may be onto something here. But if it's an javascript/id issue, why would it work on every other one and not just the first one on the page?

Comment: did you double check the variable in 'debugger' ?

Comment: Once it stops type iconClass; in the console and it will return the value...  Look to see it says btnRotate.clicked for every one of them (play button to move next....)

Comment: it is sporadically adding the clicked variable. never on the first click and sporadic after that.

Comment: Is this online somewhere i can browse to?

Comment: figured it out thanks to this post. i was essentially using 2 click listeners.

Comment: Awesome Jason! Glad to hear it.  Debugger; and console are so powerful and quick to find the problems and many people dont know to use it.